# Java Generic extend on return of method cast error

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have a method that returns a list of a generic type, method shown below.

```
    protected <T extends SQLDataBean> List<T> getJavaListFromOracleArray(Array array) throws SQLException
```

I then have an object called a ReplacementBean that extends SQLDataBean.

In another class I have a `List<ReplacementBean>` with a set method taking in a `List<ReplacementBean>`

What I have found and I'm not sure why is I can not call the above listed method inside the set.  Meaning this gives a compile time error:

```
setReplacements(this.getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray()));
```

However the following compiles and works fine.

```
List<ReplacementsBean> temp = this.getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray());
setReplacements(temp);
```

I have also tried to cast inside the set method as follows, but it also has a compile time error.

```
setReplacements((List<ReplacementsBean>)this.getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray()));
```

Is there any way to not have to do the two line process of setting a temporary local variable before calling my set method?  While it does work, it would be nice to not have to do it.

calling the following:

```
setReplacements(this.getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray()));
```

results in a error of `setReplacements(List<ReplacementsBean>) is not applicable for the arguments List<SQLDataBean>`

The setReplacements code is as follows:

```
public void setReplacements(List<ReplacementsBean> replacements)
{
    this.replacements = replacements;
}
```

Also if I try this:

```
setReplacements((List<ReplacementsBean>)this.getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray()));
```

I get the error Cannot cast from `List<SQLDataBean>` to `List<ReplacementsBean>`.

Comment: Also show the code of setReplacements.

Comment: edited to include error and setReplacements Code.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those cases where the compiler type inference isn't quite as good as you might like it to be.  The following should work, where you specify the generic method type parameter explicitly:

```
setReplacements(this.<ReplacementsBean>getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray()));
```

In the temporary variable case

```
List<ReplacementsBean> temp = this.getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray());
setReplacements(temp);
```

the compiler is forced to instantiate `<T>` as `<ReplacementsBean>` to make the assignment work.

Comment: so the answer is that due to how the compiler interprets I have to do the two step with the temporary variable.

Comment: @user1735869 or use the explicit `this.<ReplacementsBean>getJavaList...` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside the compiler the following is done:

```
List<X> temp = getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray());
setReplacements(temp);
```

where X must be ReplacementsBean or a child thereof. And that is open-ended. In many more formally typed languages the X is resolved, in java not. Hence the need for:

```
setReplacements(<ReplacementsBean>getJavaListFromOracleArray(in.readArray()));
```

However this "defect" is also a **clear symptom**: probably `getJavaListFromOracleArray` does unsafe generics.

Mind also that the function `setReplacements` might be overriden in a child class with as parameter a `List<ReplacementsBeanChild>`.